# Fit a large size image in viewport without sliding

Tags: html, css

I have tried to add the image in the page, but end up the image is too big for the viewport.
[enter link description here](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/swordartonline/images/b/b0/Sinon_GGO.png/revision/latest?cb=20140727063131)
I tried some way that has been posted put none of them working. Is there anyway to do this without resizing the image by using fixed width/height

Comment: _“I tried some way that has been posted put none of them working.”_ - please don’t just vaguely mention that you had tried something and it “didn’t work” - show us_ what you tried! Please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: https://codepen.io/asadashino/pen/BxEQKg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
width : 100%
```

Here some update on your codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjMWYo

Comment: It would make the image blurry

Comment: what exactly do you need with this image? you need to use big size image if you want it to be clearer ^^

Comment: you can see my codepen again, i change the image. i think it depends on the size of image.

Comment: it will be better to use svg image if you want it to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

try using `max-width:100%` on image. Something like this:

```css
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1700x400" />
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. I have already put image inside a <div> and added max-width to it

Comment: In codepen it doesn't look like in my browser. I wrote in VS code and use Chrome to run

Comment: Sharing Codepen for your question  in comments is not a good practice. If you wish folks here should look into your issue and try to help you out. Then add you code snippet in your question.

Comment: Meanwhile, In codepen your image is coming already small from server. So can't predict what issue you are facing. Please share some more info.